# Extract String in useCase in Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My task is to show error when user click submit (if there is one).

For that I have :

```
data class ValidationResults(
    val successful: Boolean,
    val errorMessage: String? = null
)
```

Example of input mistake:

```
@Singleton
class ValidateUsername @Inject constructor() {
    fun execute (username: String) : ValidationResults{

       if(username.isBlank()){
                return ValidationResults(
                    successful = false,
                    errorMessage =  R.string.register_user_empty_user_field.toString()
                )
            }
```

In presentation:

```
if(state.username != null){
        Text(
            text = state.usernameError,
            color = Color.Red
        )
    }
```

But I only get Int
[image]

How to properly call String from Resources.

EDIT:
I get this error if using:

```
stringResource(id = R.string.register_user_empty_user_field)
```

> @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I injected Application in ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class RegistrationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val validateUsername: ValidateUsername,
    private val validatePassword: ValidatePassword,
    private val validateRepeatedPassword: ValidateRepeatedPassword,
    private val applicationContext: Application
    ) : ViewModel()
```

And then just send it to function and use it like this:

```
 errorMessage = applicationContext.getString(R.string.register_user_username_field_to_short)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need call `stringResource(id = R.string.register_user_empty_user_field)`